# Derivation of the transformation law for spinors

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, spinors

I'm reading the book *Quantum Field Theory: An Integrated Approach* by Eduardo Fradkin, and I got stuck where the transformation law for spinors
$$
\psi'(x') = S(\Lambda) \psi(x)
$$
is derived.

In chapter 2, an infinitesimal Lorentz's transformation
$$
\Lambda^\mu_\nu = \delta^\mu_\nu + \omega^\mu_\nu
$$
is assumed, where $\omega^{\mu\nu}$ is infinitesimal and antisymmetric. Suddenly, an extra antisymmetric matrix $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$ appears, and the transformation law for spinors is, for some reason that is unknown to me, written as (equations 2.116 from the book)
$$
S(\Lambda) = I - \dfrac{i}{4} \sigma_{\mu\nu} \omega^{\mu\nu} + \cdots\ .
$$

Though this quick derivation for an infinitesimal $S(\Lambda)$ looks a bit confusing to me, I can (more or less) achieve to understand it, since I have seen similar expressions when studying the generators for Lorentz's transformations.

What is making me feel unconfortable is the $1/4$ factor. First, I thought it could be that the terms resulting from the product $\sigma_{\mu\nu} \omega^{\mu\nu}$ were repeated four times due to both matrices being antisymmetric. However, I expanded the product by hand, and realized that all non-null terms are repeated only twice, which suggests me that this factor should be $1/2$.

What am I missing about the expression for $S(\Lambda)$?

Comment: ... Page, chapter, equations?

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Chapter 2, equations (2.116)

Comment: Include it in the question.

Comment: I don't have the particular book, but if I am not mistaken, the numerical factor is usually convention-dependent. You can first put a 1/2 to account for the antisymmetry of the generators (optional), then the extra 1/2 depends on how you define this $\sigma_{\mu\nu}$. Some authors use $[\gamma_\mu,\gamma_\nu]$, others use $\gamma_{[\mu}\gamma_{\nu]}=\frac{1}{2}[\gamma_\mu,\gamma_\nu]$. I don't think it plays any role whatsoever so I wouldn't bother much.